# condition for the evaluation of trigonometric limits

Tags: limits

Are the trigonometric limits such as

$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{sin(x)}{x} = 1$ valid only for all positive $x$ ?

For example , my book says that

$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{sin(-1)}{-1} = sin1$ instead of just $1$.

So what is the condition for these limits to be valid ? Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are the trigonometric limits such as
>
> $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$ valid only for all positive $x$ ?

No, in fact: $x$ isn't limited to positive values in the limit above... It can be positive and negative when tending to $0$.

> For example , my book says that
>
> $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(-1)}{-1} = \sin 1$ instead of just $1$.

But there's no variable $x$ here! This is similar to writing:
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{-5}{4} = -\frac{5}{4}$$
because $\tfrac{-5}{4}$ is simply a constant, not depending on $x$.

The same holds for your example, the only difference being that this constant involves a sine-function. Note that the sine function is an *odd function* which means that $\sin(-a)=-\sin a$ for any value $a$, so also:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(-1)}{-1} = \frac{\sin(-1)}{-1} = \frac{-\sin(1)}{-1}=\sin 1$$
Although it may look similar, this has *nothing to do* with the (standard) limit:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$$

Comment: oh so you mean that the limit dos not have an effect on the $\frac{sin(-1)}{-1}$ since it’s already a constant

Comment: Indeed! The fact that they're using a sine function and the value $-1$ might confuse you, but it's not related to that limit you mention. They could've written $\lim_{x \to 0}\tfrac{\sin(-7)}{-7}$ and the answer would have been $\tfrac{\sin 7}{7}$, after simplifying.

Comment: Alright thank you very much for your help !

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

We have $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{\sin x}{x}=1$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0^-} \frac{\sin x}{x}=1$. $x$ can be negative.

$\displaystyle \frac{\sin(-x)}{-x}= \frac{-\sin(x)}{-x}=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$  and $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin (-x)}{-x}=1$.

$\displaystyle \frac{\sin(-1)}{-1}$ is a constant and it is always equal to $\sin 1$. So we obviously have $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(-1)}{-1}=\sin 1$.

Comment: Thank you ,But isn’t the identity supposed to be valid for all general angles ? Or is it that $sin1$ is approximately equal to $1$ ?

Comment: $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is a limit and is not a function of $x$.  This limit is $1$, but it does not mean that $\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$.

Comment: I agree . It means that as $x$ approaches zero , the value of $\frac{sinx}{x}$ approximately equals $1$ . But isn’t $-1$ very close to zero already ?

Comment: Note that $\frac{\sin (-x)}{-x}=\frac{\sin x}{x}$. So $\frac{\sin (-1)}{-1}$ is as close to $0$ as $\frac{\sin (1)}{1}$.  But  $\frac{\sin (-1)}{-1}$ is a constant and does not depend on $x$.  It's value does not depend on the limit $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}$.

Comment: Oh okay ! I understood it ! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\sin x$ and $x$ are **both odd functions** thus $\frac{\sin x}{x}=\frac{\sin -x}{-x}$ and the limit for $x\to 0^-$ and for $x\to 0^+$ is the same.

Answer (score 1):

For $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{sin(-1)}{-1} =\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-sin(1)}{-1} = sin(1)$$

You are taking limit of a constant which is the same as the constant itself.

For $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$$

You are taking the limit of a function and you need some mathematics to prove it.

The limit exist because you get the same result for positive or negative x.